# Docker-Compose: How to pass the Docker Machine IP address to a service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a system of spring-boot microservices that is set up with docker compose, it contains a emailService. The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  email-service:
    image: APP/email-service
    environment:
      - DOCKER_IP_ADDRESS=${DOCKER_IP_ADDRESS}
```

I need the docker machne ip address in emailSevice because it has to send emails with some URLs.
How can I dot to pass the Docker machine ip address to the emailService?

Comment: Why would you need to pass the ip address? Just read it from within the container. Plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: @Rob becasue emailServices sends an email with an URl and it is like http://DOCKER_IP:port/service that allow to the user access to the app. So I need to pass the docker machine address.

Comment: I don't use docker-machine so maybe i'm missing something here but you should still be able to get the ip address from within the container. Try `ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`

Comment: Why not use the service name?

Comment: @TarunLalwani The thing is that the email that is sent contains a URL, if I use the service name the URL would be http://serviceName:9090/app. For that reason I need to pass the docker ip address, so the email will contain the IP to access to the app.

Comment: What kind of OS is this on? Is it any cloud? Also how about using something like `ipinfo.io/ip` at the start of the container

Comment: Wel, how I'm working in a local environment with Windows 10, Docker for Windows. Is it no possible pass it in the docker compose file?